# ¿Cómo sincronizar un NumericUpDown o TextBox con un DateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Básicamente lo que quiero hacer es que al poner un numero en el Numericupdown me de como resultado en el DateTimePicker la fecha de ese numero del mes actual

Por ejemplo: estamos en el mes de Enero
si yo pongo en un Textbox o NumericUpDown el numero 20, quiero que en el DateTimePicker aparezca la fecha de 20/01/2023

¿Es posible esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El **DateTimePicker** tiene la **propiedad ShowUpDown** la cual obtiene o establece un valor que indica si se utiliza un control de botón de número(también conocido como control de flechas) para ajustar el valor de fecha y hora. Lo que debes hacer es seleccionar el **DateTimePicker**, ir a las propiedades y darle a la **propiedad ShowUpDown** el valor de **true**, esto hará que que el **DateTimePicker** también funcione como un  **NumericUpDown** para establecer las fechas.

**Actualización**:

Supongo que tendrás quizás un botón para realizar esa acción, el código sería:

```
DateTime fechaInicioMes = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
int dias = Convert.ToInt16(txtDias.Text);
DateTime nuevaFecha = fechaInicioMes.AddDays(dias - 1);    
dateTimePicker1.Value = nuevaFecha;
```

Lo que se hace aquí es declarar la **variable fechaInicioMes** la cual a partir de la fecha actual, guardará el dia **1** para el mes actual y el año actual, es decir el primer día del año y mes actual. Después en la **variable dias** guardariamos la cantidad de dias que queremos desplazar a partir del primer dia del mes. Posteriormente en la **variable nuevaFecha** guardamos esa suma de días a partir del primer día del mes, usando el **método AddDays**, el cual suma días a determinada fecha, por último le damos al **DateTimePicker** el valor guardado en la **variable nuevaFecha**.

**Nota:**
Asumo que el total de días lo escribes en un **TextBox** al cual yo llamo **txtDias**. Recuerda ademas que tienes que hacer validaciones ya que si en el **TextBox** escribes **40**, obtendrás más dias de los que admite cualquier mes y la nueva fecha obtenida tendrá un mes diferente al actual, recuerda también que hay meses que tienen **30**, **31**, **28** o **29** días.

Comment: Hola Japv, entiendo lo que me comentas pero lo que quiero es asignar un numero de día ya sea al numericupdown o un textbox para que así el datetime picker cambie a la fecha del mes actual correspondiente a ese numero día que establezca, esto así ya que el datetimepicker estará oculto

Comment: Deja ver si entiendo, vas a tener un textbox y ahi pondrias el valor 250 por ej, y tu lo que quieres es obtener el dia 250 del año que alomejor el dia 250 del año es 3 de agosto, eso es lo que quieres?

Comment: Si, eso es lo quiero pero en relacion al mes actual y no al año, por ejemplo en el textbox pongo el numero 20 y que me de como resultado el 20/01/2023

Comment: @LuisVelazquez edita tu pregunta y aclara todo eso que me explicas si es posible con algun ejemplo para que se te pueda entender mejor

Comment: ok ya edite la pregunta

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Japv es justo lo que buscaba